# Jupyter | How to rotate 3D graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am not sure about how to rotate graph in Python Jupyter notebook, its static for me and not rotate on mouse movement

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
z =[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To enable interactivity you need to use the `notebook` backend of matplotlib. You can do this by running `%matplotlib notebook`.

This must be done before you plot anything, e.g.:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d    

fig = ...
```

#### Update 2023-07-13

This answer is getting old and the choice of backends have changed over time (I used the `widget` backend for many years).

The current best choice for interactive plots in Jupyter Notebooks is supposedly the [ipympl](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/) backend.
You need to install it and then use

```
%matplotlib ipympl
```

Comment: when i add that to my Colab notebook, it doesn't show the animation at all :( ... even if I remove the line, I have to restart the kernel for the stationary graph to show up

Comment: Note that this is is an alternative to something like `%matplotlib inline`, so don't try to combine them.  The effects of `matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize']` do not quite match so you will want to adjust those as well.

Comment: I had the same issue as you, @Raksha you can take a look here: https://medium.com/lambda-school-machine-learning/making-animations-work-in-google-colaboratory-new-home-for-ml-prototyping-c6147186ae75 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602588/matplotlib-3d-scatter-animations

Comment: If someone else has the same problem as @Raksha, you need to put `%matplotlib notebook` at the very top of your code, before importing your modules. And restart your kernels. Maybe the answer yould be edited to reflect that more general solution.

Comment: @FreyaW Good point! I've updated the answer to move the `%matplotlib` magic to the top.

Comment: @HannesOvrén Even after adding the line `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `%matplotlib inline` and restarting the kernel, I'm still not able to have an interactive 3D plot that could rotate! Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Running the exact same code as OP with %matplotlib notebook at the top in Jupyter Notebook and all I get is a blank screen at the output.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when running jupyter in `vscode`

Comment: @JulesG.M. I tried it in VS Code, too. It behaves definitely as you describe it. When I try it in a browser, however, with
%matplotlib notebook at the very beginning, I get:
Javascript Error: IPython is not defined

Comment: @JulesG.M., @stanislav-koncebovski, my experience is that which matplotlib backend you should use depends on which versions of matplotlib and jupyter you are currently using. E.g. I sometimes use the `widget` backend instead of `notebook`, especially when running in JupyterLab. I guess running it in vscode might give the same type of problems. Making sure you run the latest versions of everything is probably a good idea also.

Comment: `%matplotlib widget` works best in VS code.

Comment: @nalyd88 Thanks, I've updated the answer. However, it seems like `ipympl` is the preferred choice these days. Worked fine in VS Code for me.

Comment: `ipympl` not working when I am using jupyter notebook in chrome...

Answer (score -2):

As described on matplotlib website you can create an interactive graph by importing `mplot3d`. Please use the following sample [Rotate Axes](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/mplot3d/rotate_axes3d.html).

I am going to include the code just in case the link is not available in future.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# load some test data for demonstration and plot a wireframe
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.1)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=5, cstride=5)

# rotate the axes and update
for angle in range(0, 360):
    ax.view_init(30, angle)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.001)
```

Comment: this does not work in OP context (he clearly states he is using a Jupyter Notebook)

Comment: @ManuelG Granted it doesn't offer interactivity (With the code update now it does). But the code runs on a Jupyter Notebook, the link also has an example.

Comment: this doesn't work for me on Google Colab :(