# How would you go about plotting this data in 3d over time?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

So,

The data looks like this:

[image: data] (the spaces represent different columns, and the data represents 10 particles going around a central particle "Sun" and at different time steps in this case every 1,000 days for 3.6 million days )

and I've been running into trouble trying to make plots for it and I was wondering what I've been doing wrong and a best way to go forward to my ultimate goal of making a 3d animation of the data (x,y,z over time)

I've tried multiple things but I'll just put the simple plot version i was trying yesterday(you'll see some left over variables and importing library's

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random import randint
import matplotlib.animation 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

import pandas as pd


arc = open('data10id_1S.csv', 'r')
lines = arc.readlines()

a = []

newList = []
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    if lines[i][:2] == 't=':
    
        if i != 0:
            newList = newList + [a]
            s = lines[i].replace(',','').split()
            t = float(s[1]) 
    

    else:
        s = lines[i].replace(',','').split()
        #  storing the particles data
        data = pd.DataFrame[float(s[1]), 
            float(s[3]), 
            float(s[9]), 
            float(s[5]), 
            float(s[11]), 
            float(s[7]), 
            float(s[13])]
         a = [data]


        # setting the particels variables
        m = float(s[1])
        x = float(s[3])
        vx = float(s[9])
        y = float(s[5])
        vy = float(s[11])
        z = float(s[7])
        vz = float(s[13])
        e = float(s[15])
        axis = float(s[17])
        a = a + [data]

        # setting the central particles variables
        px = a[0][1]
        pvx = a[0][2]
        py = a[0][3]
        pvy = a[0][4]
        pz = a[0][5]
        pvz = a[0][6]
        pm = a[0][0]
      fig = plt.figure()
      ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)



         lines = ax.plot(x,y,z)


         ax.set_xlim3d([-20.0, 20.0])
         ax.set_xlabel('x')


         ax.set_ylim3d([-20.0, 20.0])
         ax.set_ylabel('Y')


         ax.set_zlim3d([-20.0, 20.0])
         ax.set_zlabel('Z')
         ax.set_title("3D Plot over Time")
        
         line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, t, 3652500, fargs=(data, lines), interval=10, blit=True)
        
         plt.show()
```

here's a link to the file I don't know why it's in this format but here's the whole thing (I'm in a Linux VM and the only way I know how to share this is through gdrive)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSgy0laiBW_lAHcXwhuWFq6LhS8oEA2oWeVjjtXQfWI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you include your data file (or even just part of it) in a format other than .png? That way we can try to look at it and help you!

Comment: I added a link to the file through gdrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Overview

Here is a good starting point for you. It is a program to plot the positions over time as part of an animation. All it really does is creates lists of coordinates `(x,y,z)` from the data file. Once the lists are created, you can write a short animate function that plots all points that are present at a given time.

THIS IS A MINIMAL EXAMPLE!!!

There are a lot of directions you could go (updating size/mass of the objects, path tracing, color coding, etc). Have fun!

#### Helpful links

Animation docs:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

3d scatter plots:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

Scatter animations:
[Matplotlib 3D scatter animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602588/matplotlib-3d-scatter-animations)

#### Code

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import math
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random import randint
import matplotlib.animation 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

import pandas as pd

arc = open('data10id_1S.csv', 'r')
lines = arc.readlines()

xList = []
yList = []
zList = []
j = 1
while j < len(lines) -8:
    tempX = []
    tempY = []
    tempZ = []
    while (lines[j][:2] != 't='):
        s = lines[j].replace(',',' ').split()
        #  storing the particles locations
        tempX.append(float(s[3]))
        tempY.append(float(s[5]))
        tempZ.append(float(s[7]))
        j += 1
    j+=1   
    xList.append(tempX)
    yList.append(tempY)
    zList.append(tempZ)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')

ax.set_xlim3d([-5.0, 5.0])
ax.set_xlabel('x')


ax.set_ylim3d([-5.0, 5.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')


ax.set_zlim3d([-5.0, 5.0])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title("3D Plot over Time")

pts = ax.scatter(xList[0], yList[0], zList[0], s=30)

def animate(i):
    # setting data to new scatter coordinates
    pts._offsets3d = (xList[i], yList[i], zList[i])

    return pts

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(xList), interval=5, repeat=False, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's all I needed a good way forward, I'm a physics major who never took a coding class so a lot of my knowledge is scattered.

Comment: No worries! Please accept the answer if it is the one you like!!